# Position Randomisation by shuffle () in psychopy

Tags: psychopy

I have 4 text stimuli which I want to randomise their locations.
I did this at the beginning of routine

```
Posi=[’[4.95,0]’,’[-4.95,0]’,’[0,4.95]’,’[0,-4.95]’]
shuffle(Posi)
```

Then, turning to the builder, I typed

```
$Posi[0], $Posi[1]
```

in the ‘position’ column and so on, for the 4 stmuli. I also set that to ‘set every repeat’

But I keep getting this

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: [-4.95,0]
```

I don’t understand how I should change the input, because there is no problem if I just plainly put [x,y] into position.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you use those single quotes you are telling python that you are creating a string, that is a list of characters - not a number. Programs have *types* which say what a value is. '0.44' is a string of characters not a number.

```
>>> pos = [[0.2,0.0],[0.1,1]]
>>> pos[0]
[0.2, 0.0]
>>> pos[0][0]
0.2
>>> pos[0][0]+ 3.3
3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

### Produce a list of numerical coordinates, not strings

Like brittUWaterloo already stated, you are currently effectively creating a list of *strings*, not a list of lists (of coordinates), as you intended:

```
>>> pos = ['[4.95, 0]', '[-4.95, 0]', '[0, 4.95]', '[0, -4.95]']
>>> pos[0]
'[4.95, 0]'
>>> type(pos[0])
<class 'str'>
```

*Note that I also changed the variable name and inserted spaces to produce more readable code that follows common coding style guidelines.*

So, the first thing you need to do is remove the quotation marks to stop producing strings:

```
>>> pos = [[4.95, 0], [-4.95, 0], [0, 4.95], [0, -4.95]]
>>> pos[0]
[4.95, 0]
>>> type(pos[0])
<class 'list'>
```

### Putting it to work in the Builder

> Then, turning to the builder, I typed
>
> ```
> $Posi[0], $Posi[1]
> ```

What you are trying to achieve here is, I believe, using the x, y coordinates of the very first element of the (shuffled) list of possible coordinates. I believe the current syntax is not fully correct; but let's have a closer look what would potentially happen if it were:

```
>>> pos[0], pos[1]
([4.95, 0], [-4.95, 0])
```

This would produce *two* coordinate pairs (the first two of the shuffled list). That's not what you want. You want the x and y coordinates of the first list pair only. To get the first coordinate pair only, you would to (in "pure" Python):

```
>>> pos[0]
[4.95, 0]
```

Or, in the Builder, you would enter

```
$pos[0]
```

into the respective coordinates field.

### Summary

So to sum this up, in your Code component you need to do:

```
pos = [[4.95, 0], [-4.95, 0], [0, 4.95], [0, -4.95]]
shuffle(pos)
```

And as coordinate of the Text components, you can then use

```
$pos[0]
```